# How do I copy calendar events from subscribed calendars to import into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a database of shifts worked for our medical residency in Google Sheets. I have found and modified a script that looks in our user's Google Calendar events and transfers all the events between given dates into a useful format in Google Sheets. I have only been able to get this to work with the "native" Google calendars, which is an issue.

All our residents' shift information and shift swaps comes from a service, Amion, that generates a calendar feed for each resident. To create an easy-to-read consensus calendar, we have added each of these calendar subscription links into Google Calendar. What I would like to do is copy each of these calendar events/shifts into our Google Sheets database but I don't know how.

QUESTION: What command (s) do I use in my script, to copy these subscribed calendar events into Google sheets?

**UPDATE:** When I try to use CalendarApp.getAllCalendars() in the below code, I end up with the error code, "TypeError: Cannot find function getEvents in object ".

```
{
var mycal = "***@gmail.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2018 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 31, 2018 23:59:59 CST"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Start", "Event End", "Last Updated"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5); range.setValues(header);
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5); range.setValues(details);
}
```

Comment: As I stated above, I'm able to retrieve events from my default/owned calendar. What I'm trying to do is retrieve them from subscribed calendars.

Comment: @PirateBill and? The documentation for `CalendarApp` clearly offers a function which does exactly what you want - gets all calendars, even subscribed ones. Then its a simple check if the calendar being iterated is owned or not. You have provided 0 code, so we can only conclude you are not yet using this function, and thus recommend you use this function.

Comment: You have to loop in the different calendars you get in the object returned by getAllCalendars()..  Use a for loop. Also : don't write each row each time you read the value, build an array and write it in the end otherwise you'll rapidly get time out issues.